# Should I hyphenate "moon phase"?

Tags: nouns, hyphenation

Struggling to find an answer for whether "moon phase" should be hyphenated or not?

Example sentence:

> Attacks were highest during the first moon phase.

Comment: Just call it "lunar phase".

Comment: A general rule, often contradicted, is that you would only hyphenate "moon phase" if using the words as an adjective (vs a noun).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moon+phase%2Cmoon-phase&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmoon%20phase%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmoon%20phase%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMoon%20phase%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMoon%20Phase%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMOON%20PHASE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoon%20-%20phase%3B%2Cc0  shows the hyphenated version is very rare. To simply find out which variant is more common you can easily do your own ngram query,

Comment: @k1eran - Ngram is quite unreliable with regard to hyphenated words.

Comment: @HotLicks seems you are right. I adjusted the ngram to include spaces to the left of the hyphen, to the right, and to both sides and I got extra hits missed earlier. The total with hyphens now looks bigger, even combined still less than non-hyphenated, though data does indeed seem unreliable. So I won't say more on this. New version is : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moon+phase%2Cmoon-phase%2Cmoon+-+phase%2Cmoon+-phase%2Cmoon-+phase&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmoon%20phase%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmoon%20phase%3B

Answer (score 0):

For a noun, here abstract, then either "lunar phase" or "phase of the moon".

"Moon phase" is more likely to be used adjectivally, though…

"If your wristwatch fails at night, try using a moon-phase clock…"